# How to remove tags from a pdf

Tags: pdf, tags, abcpdf

I have this pdf where there are tags like this:

```
62 0 obj
<< /Type /StructElem /S /DokumentNavn /P 56 0 R /K 2 /Pg 58 0 R >>
endobj
60 0 obj
<< /Type /StructElem /S /Bundtekst /P 56 0 R /K 0 /Pg 58 0 R >>
endobj
61 0 obj
<< /Type /StructElem /S /ReferenceLinjer /P 56 0 R /Lang (da) /K 1 /Pg 58 0 R >>
endobj
68 0 obj
<< /Type /StructElem /S /Fritekst /P 56 0 R /K 6 /Pg 58 0 R >>
endobj
```

I have "removed" them by overwriting them with %
However the tool that checks against a whitelist still complains
So I'm thinking that maybe the tags are also used in the binary sections of the pdf.
Can abcpdf remove tags or is there another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) can remove structure information from PDF documents.

Below is a sample code for the task:

```
public static void saveWithoutStructureInformation(string input, string output)
{
    using (PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(input))
    {
        document.RemoveStructureInformation();

        document.SaveOptions.RemoveUnusedObjects = true;
        document.Save(output);
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.